# IntelliJ Idea 15 shows dependency packages with project packages

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

IntelliJ Idea 15 CE is showing packages from libraries/dependencies in the Project's Packages View. This only happens if root package of the project is common with those of some dependencies.

For ex. my project's root package is **org**. So all the dependencies which also have **org** package like **org.apache.logging** are also being listed in my project's packages.

This is a gradle project we are talking about. And Its not "Libraries" tree I am referring to.

Is this a configurable behaviour or a bug? I couldn't find any configuration to disable it.

**Update:**
Issue has been submitted at IntelliJ Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147677

A screenshot of the problem is attached in this question: [IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE Project->Packages includes library packages, empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783239)

Comment: Added a screenshot to this copy of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783239/intellij-idea-15-ce-project-packages-includes-empty-dependency-packages

Comment: @stolsvik that's great. Btw I had created an issue as well. Now I have made a comment with your screenshot on the issue. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147677