# IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE Project->Packages includes library packages, empty

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: Example of problem]

(This seems to be the exact same problem that is [described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601816/intellij-idea-15-shows-dependency-packages-with-project-packages), I just wanted to add a screenshot to it.)

*"IntelliJ Idea 15 CE is showing packages from libraries/dependencies in the Project's Packages View. This only happens if root package of the project is common with those of some dependencies."*

The "wrong" packages included does not have any content - there are no classes in them: When you first open the leaf packages, there are "arrows" on them, but they disappear after a second.

The only package that should be shown here is the one containing the classes in the screenshot.

Comment: Same in ultimate version. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No solution. Seems like a bug. Someone(tm) should report it! .. AND that is done by original reporter! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147677